# "crash" vs. "wreck" for [road/air] accident in AmEng

Tags: american-english, word-usage, vernacular, dialects

What's the difference between those terms in relation to a road or air accident?

***crash***

> *verb*
>
> 1. (*Aeronautics*) to cause (an aircraft) to hit land or water violently resulting in severe damage or (of an aircraft) to hit land or water in this way
> 2. (*Automotive Engineering*) to cause (a car, etc.) to collide with another car or other object or (of two or more cars) to be involved in a collision
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. a collision, as between vehicles
> 2. (*Aeronautics*) a sudden descent of an aircraft as a result of which it hits land or water [CED](http://dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/crash)

***wreck***

> *noun* An automobile or railroad collision or accident: *witnessed a wreck on the highway*.
>
> *verb* To cause the destruction of in a collision: *wrecked the car by hitting a tree*. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/wreck)

Please, compare the following examples:

> *His parents died in a **car/plane crash***.
>
> *His parents died in a **car/plane wreck***.

-and-

> *I **crashed the car** by hitting a tree*.
>
> *I **wrecked the car** by hitting a tree*.

-and-

> *The helicopter/truck **crashed into** their home*.
>
> *The helicopter/truck **wrecked into** their home*.

-and-

> *He witnessed a terrible **crash** on the highway*.
>
> *He witnessed a terrible **wreck** on the highway*.

Comment: *Cracked up* is [1990s slang](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cracked+up+the+car&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccracked%20up%20the%20car%3B%2Cc0). I don't think you need to worry about it today.

Comment: @PeterShor OK. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: FWIW, this question is the first time I have ever seen "crack up" refer to anything other than uproarious laughter (native to U.S. Great Lakes - Midwest Region)

Comment: @cobaltduck How about "cracked up to be" as in, "The pizza is not what it's cracked up to be"? http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cracked+up+to+be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normally wouldn't use "crackup" for a plane, nor would you ever use "cracked" in this sense.  And "crackup" is informal and implies a less severe wreck, so it normally would not be used to describe an incident resulting in death.

"Crash" and "wreck" are *almost* interchangeable in this sense, though, eg, "wreck" is more idiomatic for an incident involving a train.

(The subtle difference between "crash" and "wreck" is that saying you "saw" a "crash" *tends* to imply you actually saw the incident occur, while seeing a "wreck" does not so much.)

Comment: This is a really good answer. The only thing left out of it is that there are regional differences in usage in the US:  When referring to automobiles, "crash" is more common in NE - Southern and Mid-western areas use "wreck" instead. The lines of demarcation run similar to *proofed/carded"*, *license plate/tag* and *soda/pop*. (Not sure about the West.)

Comment: Tying to the subtle difference noted, "wreck" has a sense to also refer to the artifact left over: the smashed vehicle is a wreck.  A "wrecker" is an alternate term for a tow truck.

Comment: I don't think "wreck" works intransitively, BTW, the "wrecker" is often spelled and prounounced "rigger" in the upper Potomac valley - possibly elsewhere.

Comment: @Rob_Ster - It might be said that, say, a stock car racer "wrecked" in his latest race (though "crashed" would be closer to the norm, and I don't doubt that stock car racers have their own jargonistic terms as well).

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think *plane crash* is typically when it hits the ground or a building; mid-air would almost always be referred to as a *collision*, right?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm coming from a British English background, I would suggest that a vehicle can (sometimes*) be recovered and repaired after a *crash* but definitely not after a *wreck*. A wreck suggests permanency and irrecoverableness (e.g. a *shipwreck*).

(* e.g. plane crashes tend to be permanent)

Collins English Dictionary: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wreck

> ### wreck
>
> **verb**
>
> 1. To involve in or  suffer disaster or destruction

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crash

> ### crash
>
> **verb**
>
> 5. to cause (an aircraft) to hit land or water violently resulting in severe damage or (of an aircraft) to hit land or water in this way
> 6. to cause (a car, etc) to collide with another car or other object or (of two or more cars) to be involved in a collision

Comment: No, definitely not. What a mechanic or other technically qualified person might say about the subject of the crash/wreck is irrelevant. Planes crash and then are repaired and fly again. Ships wreck and then are repaired and sail again. You can crash your car, have the wreck towed to a mechanic, and then ask the mechanic, “is it totalled or not?” (Is it a “total wreck” or can it be repaired?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems, generally, that 'crash' is the actual incident. 
     "I crashed into a tree."

Wreck is the result of the crash. 
      "And, it left my car a wreck"

I crashed late last night over at a friend's house, and this morning I'm a wreck.

Comment: So "wreck" is not a verb, and you cannot say "I wrecked my car"?

Comment: OMG - u wrecked havoc on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm from New York and we always say accident. When I lived in Virginia and Florida (the South) the word is always wreck, even if it was only a small accident.